# Weights for Constraint Layout in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Is there any way to use weights in **Jetpack Compose** ConstraintLayout chains like in XML:

```xml
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/first"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="#caf"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/start"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="6"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/second"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="#fac"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/first"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="4"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Currently, neither `ConstraintLayoutScope` or `ConstraintScope` provide weight functionality. `ConstraintLayoutScope` provides `createHorizontalChain(vararg elements: ConstraintLayoutReference, chainStyle: ChainStyle)` (or `createVerticalChain` respectively) but without the option to set weights to individual elements.

With guidelines, barriers and everything else integrated I feel like there's something important missing here. Is there a way to use weights in chains or emulate their behaviour? I cannot just specify a fixed width for a element since the width of the ConstraintLayout has to match the whole screen.

*Note: I understand that the new Jetpack Compose ConstraintLayout does not have a performance advantage for complex, otherwise nested, layout structures like the Android View ConstraintLayout had. I’m also aware that Row and Column provide weight functionality but I have to use ConstraintLayout in my case ([reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65570024/jetpack-compose-overlays-build-software-keyboard-with-jetpack-compose))*

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Have you tried `fillMaxWidth(faction)` modifier?
I did this and worked for me...

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ConstraintLayoutWeightDemo() {
    ConstraintLayout(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        val (refB1, refB2, refB3) = createRefs()
        Text(
            "Text 1",
            modifier = Modifier
                .constrainAs(refB1) {
                    start.linkTo(parent.start)
                    end.linkTo(refB2.start)
                }
                .fillMaxWidth(.3f) // <<<---- 30%
                .background(Color.Red)
        )
        Text(
            "Text 2",
            modifier = Modifier
                .constrainAs(refB2) {
                    start.linkTo(refB1.end)
                    end.linkTo(refB3.start)
                }
                .fillMaxWidth(.5f) // <<<---- 50%
                .background(Color.Green)
        )
        Text(
            "Text 3",
            modifier = Modifier
                .constrainAs(refB3) {
                    start.linkTo(refB2.end)
                    end.linkTo(parent.end)
                }
                .fillMaxWidth(.2f) // <<<---- 20%
                .background(Color.Blue)
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a lot. Note: this Modifier will be overriden by `width = Dimension.fillToConstraints` so use either of them

Comment: Working Solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `Modifier.horizontalChainWeight = 1f`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As Feilipe mentioned `horizontalChainWeight` worked better as `fillMaxWidth` in my case, because my chain was complicated and contained some composables with constant width.

```
   modifier = Modifier
            .height(someHeight)
            .constrainAs(component1) {
                    top.linkTo(other1.bottom)
                    start.linkTo(other2.end)
                    end.linkTo(parent.end)
                    bottom.linkTo(other3.top)
                    horizontalChainWeight = .5f  // <--- weight
              }
```