# Trying to achieve keyboard layout in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to achieve a normal keyboard layout like in this picture

[image]

However, in the past 3 hours, I've been stuck with this result and I don't know how I am supposed to replicate this, maybe I'm missing something. The keys need to have the same width and height and the rows with a smaller number of letters will be centered.

[image]

Right now my code looks like this:

```
@Composable
fun GameKeyboard() {

    val firstRow = listOf("Q", "W", "E", "R", "T", "Y", "U", "I", "O", "P")
    val secondRow = listOf("A", "S", "D", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "L")
    val thirdRow = listOf("Z", "X", "C", "V", "B", "N", "M")

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(4.dp)
    ) {
        GameKeyboardRow(firstRow)
        GameKeyboardRow(secondRow)
        GameKeyboardRow(thirdRow)
    }
}

@Composable
fun GameKeyboardRow(keyList: List<String>) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(2.dp)
    ) {
        keyList.forEach {
            GameKeyboardKey(it, Modifier.weight(1f, true))
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun GameKeyboardKey(key: String, modifier: Modifier) {

    Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
        modifier = modifier
            .aspectRatio(1f)
            .border(
                width = 2.dp,
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.outline,
                shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.small
            )
            .clickable {

            }) {
        Text(
            text = key,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Build Software Keyboard with Jetpack Compose - IME Input Method with Jetpack Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65570024/build-software-keyboard-with-jetpack-compose-ime-input-method-with-jetpack-com)

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, I found the answer myself, I will post it here if anybody else is looking for it, sometimes the answer is right in front of your eyes.

I ended up counting letters and realizing I can use the weight to space around the second and third rows.

if the first row has `n` letters, then the second row was `n-1` letters so in the `Row` view, I will have two `Spacer` views that will take the `weight / 2`. Same logic applies for third row which has `n-3` letters

```
    GameKeyboardRow(firstRow)
    GameKeyboardRow(secondRow, 1f)
    GameKeyboardRow(thirdRow, 3f)
```

And then the `Row` looks like this:

```
Row(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(2.dp)
) {
    if (marginWeight != null) {
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(marginWeight / 2))
    }

    keyList.forEach {
        GameKeyboardKey(it, Modifier.weight(1f, true))
    }

    if (marginWeight != null) {
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(marginWeight / 2))
    }
}
```

Comment: Or you could simply specify a width/height for the GameKeyboardKey Composable instead of just specifying the aspect ratio, which was forcing it to size so as to fill up the entire space, and avoid the issue altogether... But yeah do what your heart desires I guess.

Comment: Also, there's the `align` modifier that may be used. For complex UI, I absolutely go for the `Layout` Composable. It's just the best out there, and I actually end up using it for most of my UI designs. Rows and Columns are a bit too confusing but Layout gives you full control over your UX, i.e., measurement and positioning. In fact, Row and Column are built on top of it.