# How to scale item in row while hovering over in Jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am working on recreating facebook reactions with jetpack compose. Have now an issue with how I can detect when hovering over an item in a row and scale it? To be more clear I am creating [**THIS**](https://miro.medium.com/max/600/1*lF2xi_6hdc-0fvWqXcN1Cg.gif). I reused popup from jetpack compose that part is fine. But dragging/hovering over the row not sure how to scale images. Any advice or help?

Comment: Does this question helps you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65570024/build-software-keyboard-with-jetpack-compose-ime-input-method-with-jetpack-com/65634762#65634762

Comment: This is on press as I can see. I need when dragging over them to scale them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did this initial implementation for you. I hope you can continue your implementation from here:

```kotlin
@ExperimentalComposeUiApi
@Composable
fun ReactionsComponent() {
    val density = LocalDensity.current
    var selectedIndex by remember {
        mutableStateOf(-1)
    }
    val iconSize = 48.dp
    val boxPadding = 8.dp
    val iconSizePx = with(density) { iconSize.toPx() }
    val boxPaddingPx = with(density) { boxPadding.toPx() }
    val increaseSize = iconSize.times(2f)
    val icons = listOf(
        Icons.Default.Favorite,
        Icons.Default.Star,
        Icons.Default.Call,
        Icons.Default.AccountBox,
        Icons.Default.ThumbUp
    )
    Box(
        Modifier
            .height(increaseSize)
            .width(IntrinsicSize.Min)
            .pointerInteropFilter {
                val selection = ((it.x - boxPaddingPx) / iconSizePx).toInt()
                if (selection >= icons.size || selection < 0 || it.x < boxPaddingPx) {
                    selectedIndex = -1
                } else if (it.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    selectedIndex = -1 // finger released
                } else {
                    selectedIndex = selection
                }
                true
            }
    ) {
        Box(
            Modifier
                .align(Alignment.BottomStart)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(iconSize + boxPadding.times(2))
                .background(Color.LightGray, CircleShape)
        )
        Row(
            Modifier
                .align(Alignment.BottomStart)
                .width(IntrinsicSize.Min)
                .padding(boxPadding),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.Bottom
        ) {
            icons.forEachIndexed { index, icon ->
                val size = if (selectedIndex == index) increaseSize else iconSize
                Box(
                    Modifier
                        .border(1.dp, Color.LightGray, CircleShape)
                        .background(Color.White, CircleShape)
                        .height(animateDpAsState(size).value)
                        .width(animateDpAsState(size).value)
                ) {
                    Icon(
                        icon,
                        contentDescription = null,
                        tint = Color.Magenta,
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().padding(8.dp)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the result:

[image]

You can find the full code [here](https://github.com/nglauber/JetpackComposePlayground/blob/master/app/src/main/java/br/com/nglauber/jetpackcomposeplayground/screens/ReactionsTouchScreen.kt) (which includes item selection).